# Accesing website from ubuntu is very slow but works faster in windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webserver, rackspace

I have a web-server running in `rackspace` , if i access the website from my local network using windows it works fine but using ubuntu it is very slow.

Please give me some suggestions

Comment: Windows could be employing an aggressive caching policy. You could try to clear the browser cache and see if it slows down. If this is not the case, on Ubuntu you could run `curl -vvv https://sample.com` this is a quick and dirty way to see which parts of the transaction are taking longer. If you don't see anything interesting, you may try a traceroute and/or a packet capture.

Comment: I feel your pain - literally going through exactly this right now (but with a VPN) and I've literally read every log, compared every setting, and even reinstalled the OS with no avail.  Someone suggested the ISP may be doing something odd in my case - but I don't quite understand that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if the Network configurations match between your Windows and Ubuntu Linux. Mainly your DNS servers.